# From Firebase, retrieving array from the 3rd level returns "[Array]" - Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, firebase

I have the following Firebase's structure.

```
{ 
    "FORMS" : {
        "F_001" : {
            "key_1" : value1,
            "array_1" : ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
            "array_2" : ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
        }
    }
}
```

With this code,

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<my_project>.firebaseio.com"
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref().once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    process.exit(0); 
});
```

I got:

```
{ 
    "FORMS" : {
        "F_001" : {
            "key_1" : value1,
            "array_1" : "[Array]",
            "array_2" : "[Array]"
        }
    }
}
```

If I move the "F_001" key to the top-level, like the following, then I get the array data correctly.

```
{ 
    "F_001" : {
        "key_1" : value1,
        "array_1" : ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
        "array_2" : ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
    }
}
```

What can I do **without** the need to change my data structure?

And I don't wanna to request the database "part-by-part", because this script is used by another project in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the method `toString()` of the returned object `snapshot` contracts it when the level is "too deep".

The solution is not to log `snapshot.val()`, but use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
```